# TBB task_arena & task_group usage for scaling parallel_for work

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, tbb

I am trying to use the Threaded Building Blocks task_arena. There is a simple array full of '0'. Arena's threads put '1' in the array on the odd places. Main thread put '2' in the array on the even places.

```
/* Odd-even arenas tbb test */
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <tbb/blocked_range.h>
#include <tbb/task_arena.h>
#include <tbb/task_group.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 100;

int main()
{
    tbb::task_arena limited(1); // no more than 1 thread in this arena
    tbb::task_group tg;

    int myArray[SIZE] = {0};

    //! Main thread create another thread, then immediately returns
    limited.enqueue([&]{ 
        //! Created thread continues here
        tg.run([&]{
            tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, SIZE), 
                [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int> &r)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i != SIZE; i++)
                        if(i % 2 == 0)
                            myArray[i] = 1;
                }
            );
        });
    });

    //! Main thread do this work
    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, SIZE), 
                [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int> &r)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i != SIZE; i++)
                        if(i % 2 != 0)
                            myArray[i] = 2; 
                }
            );

    //! Main thread waiting for 'tg' group
    //** it does not create any threads here (doesn't it?) */
    limited.execute([&]{
        tg.wait();
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << myArray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: 
    0 2 0 2 ... 0 2
So the limited.enque{tg.run{...}} block doesn't work.
What's the problem? Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You have created `limited` arena for one thread only, and by default this slot is reserved for the master thread. Though, enqueuing into such a serializing arena will temporarily boost its concurrency level to 2 (in order to satisfy 'fire-and-forget' promise of the `enqueue`), `enqueue()` does not guarantee synchronous execution of the submitted task. So, `tg.wait()` can start before `tg.run()` executes and thus the program will not wait when the worker thread is created, joins the `limited` arena, and fills the array with '1' (BTW, the whole array is filled in each of 100 parallel_for iterations).

So, in order to wait for the `tg.run()` to complete, use `limited.execute` instead. But it will prevent automatic enhancing of the `limited` concurrency level and the task will be deferred till `tg.wait()` executed by master thread.

If you want to see asynchronous execution, set arena's concurrency to 2 manually: `tbb::task_arena limited(2)`;
or disable slot reservation for master thread: `tbb::task_arena limited(1,0)` (but note, it implies additional overheads for dynamic balancing of the number of threads in arena).

P.S. TBB has no points where threads are guaranteed to come (unlike OpenMP). Only `enqueue` methods guarantee creation of at least one worker thread, but it says nothing about when it will come. See local observer feature to get notification when threads are actually joining arenas.

Comment: Thank you, Антон! So, am I correct, that there are **two** ways: **(1)** use `tbb::task_arena limited(1) /*enqueue will enhance concurrency level from 1 to 2*/` and then `limited.enqueue{tg.run{/* some work */ flag = 1;}}` BUT next (for the main thread) something like `while(flag) tg.wait(); /* yes, it is active waiting, but, according to your answer, there is no way to force main thread to wait for tg to finish its work, because the time, when tg.run will actually start is unpredictable. Isn't it?*/` **(2)** use `tbb::task_arena limited(2)` then `limited.execute{tg.run{...}}` next `tg.wait()`

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just dont forget to declare the flag atomic